# Clang code coverage with nostdlib does not correctly link with Clang's runtime profile lib

Tags: c, x86, clang, code-coverage, bare-metal

I'm attempting to follow the instructions for clang's code coverage feature as described here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html#introduction.

Specifically I want to use code coverage without a file system x86 bare metal (nostdlib), by redirecting to a serial port as the linked document claims can be done. The documentation doesn't specify whether any particular architectures are unsupported, however when I compile the following code:

```c
int __llvm_profile_runtime;

char* AllocateCodeCoverageBuffer() {
   uint64_t size = __llvm_profile_get_size_for_buffer();

   char* buffer = AllocateZeroPool((UINTN) size);

   return buffer;
}

void WriteCodeCoverageBufferToSerial(char* buffer) {
   uint64_t buffer_size = __llvm_profile_get_size_for_buffer();

   __llvm_profile_write_buffer(buffer);

   DBG_TRACE_MSG_GUID(L"Code Coverage Results start for driver", gEfiCallerBaseName);
   PRINT_BYTES(buffer,buffer_size);
   DBG_TRACE_MSG_GUID(L"Code Coverage Results end for driver", gEfiCallerBaseName);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __llvm_profile_get_size_for_buffer
>>> referenced by CodeCoverage.c
>>>               my.lib(myCodeCoverage.obj)

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __llvm_profile_write_buffer
>>> referenced by eCodeCoverage.c
>>>               my.lib(myCodeCoverage.obj)
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\lld-link.EXE"' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

The compiler options I am using are:

```
-g -nostdlib -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Werror -Wno-array-bounds -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -include AutoGen.h -fno-common -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-tautological-constant-out-of-range-compare -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused-const-variable -Wno-varargs -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wno-microsoft-enum-forward-reference -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-stack-protector -funsigned-char -ftrap-function=undefined_behavior_has_been_optimized_away_by_clang -Wno-address -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-incompatible-library-redeclaration -Wno-null-dereference -mno-implicit-float -mms-bitfields -mno-stack-arg-probe -m64 "-DEFIAPI=__attribute__((ms_abi))" -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=small -Oz -flto -target x86_64-unknown-windows-gnu -gcodeview -funwind-tables -ftest-coverage -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping
```

The linker options are:

```
/NOLOGO /IGNORE:4001 /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF=10 /ALIGN:32 /FILEALIGN:32 /Machine:X64 /DLL /ENTRY:_ModuleEntryPoint /SUBSYSTEM:EFI_BOOT_SERVICE_DRIVER /SAFESEH:NO /BASE:0 /DEBUG:GHASH /lldmap /ALIGN:4096
```

When I inspected the llvm code, it *appears* to me that the profiler runtime cannot work without stdlib since it includes `stdio` and `stdlib`: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/compiler-rt/lib/profile/InstrProfiling.h.

The Clang documentation has me confused since GCC can support gcov profiling on Embedded systems as seen here: https://dzone.com/articles/code-coverage-embedded-target. Feels like Clang *should* also support the same for `-ftest-coverage`.

### primary questions

1. Can Clang's `-ftest-coverage` work without stdlib?
2. Can `-ftest-coverage` work on bare metal?

Thank for taking a look and providing your expertise. Please let me know if there's any info I can provide.